# Using Excel VBA - Run different conditions same time using Application.ontime

Tags: vba, excel

I want to run some conditions for one browser and do the same for browsers.When i try `Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "Chrome"` its working fine ,but when i want to do the same for 3 browser at same time its taking only last conditions.
Please find the code below and let me know how to run all 3 conditions same time.

```
a = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.Value
TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue(a)
Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "Callfunction"
Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "Chrome"
Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "FF"`
```

Comment: are there all three subroutines within your project? If so, in my opinion, all sub will be run but first one to call will be `FF`, next `Chrome` and finally `Callfunction`. Be patient(?) Check your subs (?)... etc.